# selectively put text in ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to selectively add R2 calculation to each fact. I have this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(ggpubr)
library(stringr)
library(patchwork)

freq <- fread(snakemake@input[[1]])



# Calculate R-squared separate for HLA alleles and amino acids
aa <- freq[freq$var_type == "Amino acid",]
correlation_aa <- cor(aa$AF_AFND, aa$AF_MGI)
r_squared_aa <- correlation_aa^2

hla <- freq[freq$var_type == "HLA allele",]
correlation_hla <- cor(hla$AF_AFND, hla$AF_MGI)
r_squared_hla <- correlation_hla^2

freq$label <- ifelse(freq$var_type == "HLA allele", r_squared_hla, r_squared_aa)

# Create a single ggplot object for the combined data
combined_p <- ggplot(freq, aes(x = AF_AFND, y = AF_MGI, color = gene, shape=gene)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  facet_grid(. ~ var_type) +
  geom_abline() +
  labs(x = 'Frequency in x', y = 'Frequency in y', color = 'Reference\nPopulation', shape='Gene') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu")
```

which gives this
[image]

I tried this

```
# Create a single ggplot object for the combined data
combined_p <- ggplot(freq, aes(x = AF_AFND, y = AF_MGI, color = gene, shape=gene)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  facet_grid(. ~ var_type) +
  geom_abline() +
  labs(x = 'Frequency in x', y = 'Frequency in y', color = 'Reference\nPopulation', shape='Gene') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "RdYlBu") +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = paste("R² =", round(r_squared_aa, 4)), hjust = 1, vjust = -2, size = 4, color = "red") +
  annotate("text", x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = paste("R² =", round(r_squared_hla, 4)), hjust = 1, vjust = -2, size = 4, color = "red")
```

which seems to be halfway there but just plots the correlations over each other:
[image]

How do i plot only `r_squared_aa` in the left facet and `r_squared_hla` in the right facet?

Comment: How about `+ geom_text(aes(x = Inf, y = -Inf, label = lab, data = data.frame(var_type = c("Amino Acid", "HLA allele"), lab = paste("R² =", round(c(r_squared_aa, r_squared_hla), 4)))` etc but with your formatting. I think you'll need to expose the faceting variable for the data to be placed correctly.

Comment: curious, the dupe-links have a few different approaches and examples for adding specific text to each facet. If you can't figure it out, then please add some sample data to your question (it doesn't have to be real) and then @-ping me and we'll work through errors you may be having.

Comment: @r2evans thanks I am a bit stuck and I saw that link before, but let me try and reduce the complexity of my plot and get the label working with the examples

Comment: The result almost always requires creating a new `data.frame` with just one row per label to add, with the same variables you used for `x=` and `y=` aethetics, plus all of the faceting variables. In your case, I suspect this new frame should have `AF_AFND`, `AF_MGI`, `var_type`, plus one new column that has the specific strings you want added. (Note that you can use `geom_text` to do this; while `annotate` can be used, I generally use the former.)